# How to transform code generated by ANTLR4 to a jar and remove the parsing tree inspector?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I did generate a code with ANTLR4 to parse a text input that I need it on  a site created with JavaEE  so I must transform it to .jar file to integrate it . how can I do that ?
I don t need the parsing tree inspector too that  keep showing off , I just need the output that I generated it.  How can I remove it ? 
And thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a misunderstanding here. Your generated parser + support files is all what you need to distribute. You pack those into a jar like you would do with any Java project (e.g. in Eclipse organize the parse stuff in a library and export that as jar).

In addition to that you need the ANTLR4 runtime. You can get the [minimal runtime jar](http://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-runtime-4.7.jar) from the [ANTLR4 website](http://www.antlr.org/download.html). That's it to deploy your parser.